# How to run Jetty server in a LAN?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty

I'm running in some troubling deploying my app on a Jetty Server.

If i try to access my app using localhost:8080/appName it works just fine. But if I try to use my IP it doesn't work (I mean on the same computer, ip given by the ipconfig tool)

I don't really know why, All I know is that I launch my server directly from Eclipse with the Goals set to "-jetty.host=0.0.0.0 -Djetty.port=8080 jetty:run" funny thing is, that even if I forgot or put something else for the jetty.host parameter (like Djetty.host=127.0.0.1) I always have "2014-06-18 16:59:52.238:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1b79a565{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}" in my console output.

Any idea where I do something wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you give us the full URL when you try to connect with your IP. It should work. Do not forget to indicate the `8080` port. Did you change your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I try to connect using http://10.**.***.137:8080/appName 
I've just check my hosts file nothing in here

Comment: Try to ping yourself. It looks like an error you made. But, why do you need to access to your application with IP from the computer which have the server?

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Comment: The ping to myself works, I want to because after that I want to access my app on my LAN.
My firewall is off